# newline not working in the IOS MS Teams app

Tags: python, ios, aws-lambda, newline, microsoft-teams

I have a lambda function which posts a message to both Slack and Teams. The output looks good on the desktop versions, but the '\n' newline does not work on the mobile version of the Teams app.

The code snippet in question is this

````
message = ""
for line in formated_rows:
    formated_line = ""
    for column in columns_displayed:
        if formated_line != "":
            formated_line += " | "
        formated_line += line.get(column)
    message += formated_line.rstrip() + "\n"

code_block_format_message = '```\n' + message + '```\n'
````

As you can see, the newline is inside a code block, and should be recognized, but on IOS, it looks like this

[Bugged output on IOS app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsieh.png)

Meanwhile, on Desktop, it looks fine.

[Working output on desktop app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjR0n.png)

Comment: Are you facing same issue in Android mobile as well?  Could you please share proper repro steps? Also, share the iOS Teams version details.